# design application that can create instances of class while running

Tags: java, oop, runtime

I am trying to figure out how to write an application for which I can create instances of a class(object) during the runtime of the application.

Sorry if this is a simple thing but i am still very new to OO and having trouble grasping this specific bit.

Below is some of the code that i would be using.

```
public class Task
{
    private String tskname;

    public task(String inTskName)
    {
        tskname = inTskName;
    }
}
```

In another class I would have my main

```
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

So I understand that if i wanted to create an instance (knowing that it needed to be particular quantity or particular information, i would put the following in my main and then continue on with the rest of the code.

```
Task task1 = new Task();
```

I want to be able to create tasks while the application is running. how can I do this?
I don't know how many tasks there will be. How do i allow for unlimited tasks?
Would using an array as my variable in main be the correct way of handling this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Any time you want a `Task` object, just create one.

Comment: say i have a menu that has
1. New task
2. view tasks
How do I create the code to create multiple new tasks. each being different.
Sorry, I am having trouble thinking how to best explain this.

Comment: If you need to create a `Task`, just invoke `new Task(...)`. There's nothing else to it. If you need to store them, you can use an array or a `Collection` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i allow for unlimited tasks

It seems like you just want a way of storing the tasks?  In that case just use a `List`

```
List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
tasks.add(new Task());
```